# Hybrid app : object has no method setAngle

Tags: webos

i have my plugin with id plugin1 as an object in my js view..
i have register a pdk method setAngle with js

like

```
PDL_RegisterJSHandler("setAngle", setRotationSpeed);

PDL_JSRegistrationComplete();
```

and called it like

```
var result = $('plugin1').setAngle(str);
```

here is the plugin included in my view ...

```
<object type="application/x-palm-remote" id="plugin1" width=320 height=240 x-palm-pass-event="true">
<param name="alphablend" value="true">


<param name="exe" value="photoeditor_plugin">


<param name="Param1" value="2">

 </object>
```

but it throws an exception "Object # has no method setAngle "

can any one help me ???

thnks

Comment: Link to question on [WebOS Forums](https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=13804)